# VBScript and numbers larger than Long

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, types

Is there a way to work with numbers that are larger than VBScript's `Long`?

`Long`'s range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and we need to work in an asp page with larger numbers.
We cannot work with strings and we need to sum it and do some other calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for the available data types: [VBScript Data Types](http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs6.htm)

`Currency`, `Single`, and `Double` should all work for you.

Comment: Thanks.
How do I work with the `E` in the `Single` or `Double`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Single or Double for this - just be aware of the precision as they are floating point numbers.

[More information here](http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs6.htm)